# Bootstrap awesome checkbox css does not apply styles

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to use to enhance the look of checkboxes using
[this css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/1.0.0/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css).

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="padding">
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
    <input id="excludeUser" name="excludeUser" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label data-toggle="tooltip" title="exclude" for="excludeUser">Exclude this user </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't do anything. I even tried `abc-checkbox-success` as a class as it is named in the file but that did not help.

[Here is fiddle with my try](https://jsfiddle.net/3oxmccjq/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class names are `abc-checkbox` and `abc-checkbox-success`, not `checkbox`.

Also, your fiddle is missing font awesome library:

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

```css
.padding {
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/1.0.0/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="padding">
  <div class="abc-checkbox abc-checkbox-success">
    <input id="excludeUser" name="excludeUser" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label data-toggle="tooltip" title="exclude" for="excludeUser">Exclude this user </label>
  </div>
</div>
```